# PostgreSQL - ERROR: column "date" cannot be cast to type date

Tags: postgresql, date, casting

I want to cast a specific column in my PostgreSQL database from character_varying type to type date.
phpPgAdmin gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  column "date" cannot be cast
>   to type date
>
> In Statement: ALTER TABLE
>   "public"."tablename" ALTER COLUMN
>   "date" TYPE date

What should I do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You might need to convert it to text first:

```
alter table "foo" alter column "date" type date using ("date"::text::date);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I have another problem. The date column is used in one of my views so i get the following error:

ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule

How can i overcome this ?

Comment: In that case you cannot: you need to drop the view and recreate it.

Comment: If you want to save or see the definition of the view, it's stored in pg_views btw.

Comment: How can I achieve this if my column has dates saved as dd/mm/yyyy. I get this error message with your solution.

PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "27/11/1992"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Comment: @acrogenesis: look into the `to_date()` function

Comment: I solved it setting the datestyle to DMY before the alter table. Like this: `SET datestyle = "ISO, DMY";`

thanks