# Converting sqlite3 database to postgresql in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

In my models.py file I have:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    weeks_list = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

In my settings.py file I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I have been using sqlite3 with a file called db.sqlite3. I wanted to switch to postgresql. When I try syncdb, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "weeks_list" cannot be cast automatically to type date

HINT:  You might need to specify "USING weeks_list::date".
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

go to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967022/postgresql-error-column-date-cannot-be-cast-to-type-date).resolved problem

```
alter table "foo" alter column "date" type date using ("date"::text::date);
```

Comment: Is it as follows?: `alter table "db_name" alter column "weeks_list" type date using ("weeks_list"::text::date);` And where am I supposed to type this?

Comment: type this command in postgresql command. for access to command i think must typing in command line psql. i don't use postgresql. you can search "postgresql command line"

Comment: I get `ERROR: relation "db_name" does not exist`. I tried making a new database and doing it again but still, same error.

Comment: i hope helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489105/postgresql-relation-table-does-not-exist

Comment: I'm still really lost. I've commented out `weeks_list` from my models.py and when I try to migrate, I still get the error I posted at the beginning.